# i18n in Django 1.3 doesn't work for me

Tags: django

I use Django 1.3. 
I have a clean project with:

settings.py

```
import os, sys

# absolute path to the project
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    # add to PYTHONPATH
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "apps"))

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru-ru'  


    USE_I18N = True    
    USE_L10N = True

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT,'templates'),
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'i18n_app',
)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'i18n_app.views.test'),
)
```

i18n_app/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext

def test(request):

    return render_to_response('i18n_app/test.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

templates/i18n_app/test.html

```
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
{% trans "String for trans" %}
<br>
<br>
<br>
{% blocktrans %}And one more{% endblocktrans %}
</body>
</html>
```

From project's root i run this command:

```
D:\Django\projects\testi18n>django-admin.py makemessages -l ru
processing language ru
```

Then I fill out file django.po which was created after this command and do:

```
D:\Django\projects\testi18n>django-admin.py compilemessages --traceback
processing file django.po in D:\Django\projects\testi18n\conf\locale\ru\LC_MESSAGES
```

But all I see it's english strings.
I have found too much questions about this, but no one of them hasn't helped to me.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add to your settings:

```
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', ugettext('Russian')),
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
)
```

Create an empty folder named `locale` in your projects directory

Then from your projects directory run:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l ru
```

This command will create a .po file inside your `locale` folder.Open that file and fill the empty `msgstr ""` fields with the desired translation of the `msgid` fields that sit above.
This is where you define the translation of the strings you marked for translation in the .html file.

After writing the translation of your strings run:

```
django-admin.py compilemessages
```

Comment: Yeah you're right. I've created in my project directory config/locale and it didn't work. But directory locale is fine

Answer (score 1):

django's test server needs a restart to take in account locale files changes/apparition. Otherwise translation won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the LANGUAGES setting is missing in your settings.py. Try putting in something like that:

```
ugettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('ru', ugettext('Russian')),
    ('en', ugettext('English')),
)
```

In addition make sure that 'django.core.context_processors.i18n' is in your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES setting, otherwise you won't be able to change the language. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/i18n/deployment/) for details.

What i don't understand - why do you use django-admin.py in your project directory? Basically you should use manage.py in your project directory.

```
./manage.py makemessages -l ru
```

Comment: You can edit your original post if you have other questions.  This is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to set `LOCALE_PATHS` to your locale folders